# Nicer way to do nested dot products in numpy?

Tags: numpy

I'm finding this happening to me a lot: I want to compute a matrix multiplication of the sort `(X^TX)^{-1}XX^T`, or something along these lines. I end up doing something like

```
X = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
a = np.dot(np.transpose(X), X)
b = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(a), X)
answer = np.dot(b, np.transpose(X))
```

Is there a better way to do this without resorting to the `np.matrix` type? Is there a way to do transpose without typing `np.transpose`?

Comment: You can use the `.T` notation instead of `transpose`  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html

Comment: This looks like ordinary least squares.  Take a look at [Datarobot's OLS in Python](http://www.datarobot.com/blog/ordinary-least-squares-in-python/) for a pandas/statsmodels approach without having to write out so much linear algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's explore the options a bit

```
inv=np.linalg.inv
def array1(X):
    a = np.dot(X.T, X)
    b = np.dot(inv(a), X)
    return np.dot(b, X.T)
```

Basically your code, but using the `method` expression `dot` and `.T` notation.

Testing with your `X`:

```
In [12]: array1(X)
Out[12]: 
array([[-13.5, -32.5],
       [ 10. ,  24. ]])
```

What's the matrix equivalent?

```
In [17]: M=np.matrix(X)

In [18]: (M.T*M).I*M*M.T
Out[18]: 
matrix([[-13.5, -32.5],
        [ 10. ,  24. ]])
```

The `matrix` version is more compact, but is it clearer?  It's not faster.

```
In [22]: timeit array1(X)
10000 loops, best of 3: 48.7 µs per loop

In [23]: timeit (M.T*M).I*M*M.T
10000 loops, best of 3: 95.4 µs per loop
```

First stab at a `einsum` equivalent

```
In [32]: np.einsum('ij,jk,lk',inv(np.einsum('ji,jk',X,X)),X,X)
Out[32]: 
array([[-13.5, -32.5],
       [ 10. ,  24. ]])

In [33]: timeit np.einsum('ij,jk,lk',inv(np.einsum('ji,jk',X,X)),X,X)
10000 loops, best of 3: 55.1 µs per loop
```

basically the same as the `dot` version.

The matrix version shows me that I can simplify the array version to:

```
inv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.dot(X.T))
```

(same timing)

Comment: Is there a good reason why something like `np.dot(inv(np.dot(X.T, X)), X, X.T)` is not allowed? i.e. pass multiple matrices to `np.dot()` to do in order?

Comment: The underllying C (or C++ or F) libraries don't implement that kind of chaining.  `np.dot` gets its speed by calling optimized libraries.  But that's mainly an advantage when working with large arrays, not your 2x2 example.